# Formatting floating point numbers and specify width of the result

Tags: java, formatting

The following sample code:

```
System.out.printf(" %1.1f " , 2122.3856);
```

Prints out `2122.4`

The format i specified for the above result shows that i asked for one decimal point and 1 character long for the width.  I can see the one decimal point (i.e. .4) but why did the specified width not work?

Comment: what did you expect/want to see?

Comment: You requested 1 as the _minimum_ width, not total width (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`width` specification is the minimum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#floatDWidth), not the maximum.

If you want to enforce a width that essentially makes the number's value meaningless, you should either do math (like to get the tenths place) or manipulate a conversion to string.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax (emphasis is mine):

> The width is the **minimum** number of characters to be written to the output

If your number is larger it will fully printed. How could 2122 be printed with one character?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following in the javadoc for [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) (emphasis mine):

> The optional width is a non-negative decimal integer indicating the *minimum* number of characters to be written to the output.

The width is a minimum only, and is used to pad output so that (for example) columns will line up.